# Is it proper to use qualified lookup with no namespace on the left of the scoping operator (::name) in general code?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This [sample code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) from cppreference.com:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  struct std{};
  std::cout << "fail\n"; // Error: unqualified lookup for 'std' finds the struct
  ::std::cout << "ok\n"; // OK: ::std finds the namespace std
}
```

shows how `::name` (no namespace on the left side of the scoping operator) refers to a name unambiguously.

An analogy can be made with filesystems. In filesystems, to refer to a file unambiguously, it is standard to refer to it by its absolute path, such as `/home/username/hello.txt` with a leftmost `/`.

On the other hand, it seems to be the established coding style in C++ to **never** refer to a name unambiguously, *i.e.*, the scoping operator with a right argument only is rare. But since a fully unambigious lookup exists, it is surprising that `::std::cout` isn't the standard coding style. It is always `std::cout` (no leftmost scoping operator, resulting in unqualified lookup of the leftmost namespace), which is error-prone, as the sample code shows.

Summary of the question: What serious reasons are there to support the style `std::cout` (unqualified lookup of the leftmost namespace) over `::std::cout` (qualified lookup of everything)?

Comment: *"For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages and environments."* - I fail to see the relevance of [tag:language-lawyer]. What are you looking for in the C++ standard?

Comment: Argument-dependent lookup only works for unqualified function calls, which excludes using the nested-name-specifier ​`::` if wanting to leverage ADL. Using qualified names with a leading `::` also forces developers to include possibly long-winded top-level->and->down namespace names (which could often otherwise be omitted) which may arguably make developers create abbreviated namespaces that are 1) more likely to collide with namespaces of other projects, and 3) create namespaces with abbreviations that a future reader may not understand the meaning of.

Comment: well, you never know `username` is a directory(`namespace std`) or a file(`struct std{}`) in your path example either.

Comment: I skimmed through Design&Evolution, but best I could find is *"The rules for namespaces were specifically crafted to give no advantages to a "lazy" user of global namespaces over someone who takes care not to pollute the global scope."* which is referring to the amount you have to type, I assume.

Comment: Note that namespaces have been _added_ at some point. That means they were also designed to be introduced into namespace-less programs. I guess this is where (pure) unqualified lookup rules come from, and they apply uniformly to names of types/variables and names of namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument-dependent lookup only works for unqualified function calls, which excludes using the nested-name-specifier ​`::` if wanting to leverage ADL; [[basic.lookup.argdep]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep#1)

> When the postfix-expression in a function call **is an unqualified-id**,

Using qualified names with a leading `::` also forces developers to include possibly long-winded top-level->and->down namespace names in cases where these could otherwise be omitted, leading to verbosity that could give incentive for developers to create(/refactor) namespaces with (/into using) abbreviated names that are

- more likely to collide with namespaces of other projects, and
- more difficult to understand the meaning of for a future reader.

E.g., the following

```
namespace my_projects_well_named_top_level_namespace {

namespace my_core_utils {
    void f() {};
}
    
namespace my_module_a {
    void g() {
        // Ok.
        my_core_utils::f();
        
        // Refactorer: This is too long.. let's rename the top-level.
        ::my_projects_well_named_top_level_namespace::my_core_utils::f();        
    }
}  // namespace my_module_a

}  // namespace my_projects_well_named_top_level_namespace
```

may, for the entirely wrong reasons (long and/or nested namespace names can be addressed locally within a TU using [namespace aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias); see e.g. [TotW #119](https://abseil.io/tips/119)), be re-factored into

```
namespace mp {

namespace my_core_utils {
    void f() {};
}
    
namespace my_module_a {
    void g() {       
        // Refactorer: Ok, nice!
        ::mp::my_core_utils::f();        
    }
}  // namespace my_module_a

}  // namespace mp

// Sometime later: Ehm, what is mp?
```

which, with its abbreviated name, may open up for collision (even silent ones) with 3rd party libraries which have happen to have chosen the same brilliantly abbreviated top-level namespace:

```
// ------------------- 3rdparty lib
namespace mp {
void f(int);
}  // namespace mp
 
// ------------------- your project
namespace mp {

// We are now in the same declarative region
// as that of the 3rd party library.
struct S {
    int x;
    operator int() const { return x; }
};
    
namespace my_module_a {
    void f(S) {}
}  // namespace my_module_a
    
namespace my_module_b {
    void g() { 
        // unqualified lookup _will not_ find my_module_a::f(S).
        // ADL finds mp::foo(int) from the 3rd party lib
        f(S{});  // #1
    }
}  // namespace my_module_b
}  // namespace mp
```

(where of course the author of `#1` has not followed the original refactorers intentional *rule* of using fully qualified names with leading nested-name-specifier).

Comment: Okay! Plus I learned that Thomas Koeppe, in the linked Tip of the Week #119, advocates a version of the rule I wanted: "When declaring namespace aliases and using-declarations, use fully qualified names (with leading `::`) unless you are referring to a name inside the current namespace."

Comment: @cs- Yes a namespace alias doesn't fall under lookup in the same sense as when referring to another kind of entity in a (possibly nested) namespace scope through qualified of unqualified lookup or ADL. It's arguably no "cost" to then fully qualify the name even with the leading `::`, unless the alias is aliasing a namespace that exists within the inner-most nested namespace in which the alias is declared (and indeed, Thomas adds _"[...] use fully qualified names (with leading `::`) unless you are referring to a name inside the current namespace" to the rule regarding namespace aliases"_).

Answer (score 2):

> What serious reasons are there to support the style `std::cout` (unqualified lookup of the leftmost namespace) over `::std::cout` (qualified lookup of everything)?

It's already hard enough to persuade people to write `std::`, let alone `::std::`. The former is only "error-prone" if you have no naming standards. Much simpler is to forbid naming anything `std`.

`std` should be a reserved identifier, but for compatibility with C.